# Sending code for error detection facing problem with error not able to compile code

Tags: esp8266, lcd

**MY PROJECT CODE:**

```cpp
#include ESP8266WiFi.h
#include LiquidCrystal.h
#include FirebaseArduino.h>
#include HX711.h>
#define FIREBASE_HOST "iot-based-smart-dustbin.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "ljIbV03K07rLwoHRKSaAxWzJNCb3Lh6buc76dkvb"
#define WIFI_SSID "AndroidAP"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "ashu1234"
char c; //ESP
String data   = "";  //ESP
#define DOUT  15 
#define CLK  13
#define IR1 14
#define IR2 12
HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK); // Init of library
float calibration_factor = -96650; //-106600 worked for 3-40Kg max scale setup 
const int rs = 16, en = 5, d4 = 4, d5 = 0, d6 = 2, d7 = 10;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(IR1,INPUT);
  pinMode(IR2, INPUT);
  pinMode(DOUT, INPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);     // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("WELCOME");
  delay(2000);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
//  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
    {
  //    Serial.print(".");
      delay(500);
    }
//  Serial.println();
//  Serial.print("connected: ");
//  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 
}
void loop() 
{
  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor
  float a=scale.get_units();   // a Variable to take weight values at input
  lcd.clear();
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.setFloat("Weight", a);  //to set value in firebase // value on a sent to weight variable
  if (digitalRead(IR1)==HIGH)
  {
    Firebase.setFloat("IR1", HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Location 1:High");
  }
   if (digitalRead(IR1)==LOW)
  {
    Firebase.setFloat("IR1", LOW);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);   //column, Row
    lcd.print("Location 1: Low");
  }
   if (digitalRead(IR2)==HIGH)
  {
    Firebase.setFloat("IR2", HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Location 2:High");
  }
   if (digitalRead(IR2)==LOW)
  {
    Firebase.setFloat("IR2", LOW);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Location 2: Low");
  }
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  if (a>=4)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Weight: High");
  }
   if (a<4)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Weight: Low");
  }
 delay(2000);
}
void send_msg_1()
{
  Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1");// for GSM module in TEXT mode
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+9921526975\"\r");// Phone number (change)
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Dustbin at Location 1 is full");// Message body (change as per requirement)
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println((char)26);// send message
  delay(1000);
}
```

**ERRORS I am Getting while compiling as follows:**

```cpp
sketch_jul18a:34:22: error: no matching function for call to 'HX711::HX711(int, int)'
 HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK); // Init of library
                      ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Neha\sketch_jul18a\sketch_jul18a.ino:34:22: note: candidates are:
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Neha\sketch_jul18a\sketch_jul18a.ino:23:0:
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:30:3: note: HX711::HX711()
   HX711();
   ^
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:30:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:19:7: note: constexpr HX711::HX711(const HX711&)
 class HX711
       ^
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711_Arduino_Library\src/HX711.h:19:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'HX711::HX711(int, int)'
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Too much struggling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the main problem is already in the first lines:

```
#include ESP8266WiFi.h
#include LiquidCrystal.h
#include FirebaseArduino.h>
#include HX711.h>
```

You should use the correct formatting:

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal.h"
#include "FirebaseArduino.h"
#include "HX711.h"
```

Also, HX711 does not have a constructor with arguments, so instead of

```
HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);
```

uese

```
HX711 scale;
```

and in Setup:

```
scale.begin(DOUT, CLK);
```

You probably have the code meant for a different library.

See [HX711_full_example](https://github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/examples/HX711_full_example/HX711_full_example.ino). Or use the code belonging to your used HX711 library.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious Help sir. from last many days struggling with errors. Not much familiar with Arduino IDE.. Thank you very much for help. Really grateful.

Comment: You are welcome, success with your project. If the answer solves your problem, please accept the answer (by pressing the button near the answer).